# Bootstrap 3.x for big screens how to set .container width for 1920px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having problems with bootstrap and creating a layout for bigscreens/resolutions (1920x1080). I don't have a screen with 1920x1080 resolution but i am using Chrome devtools:

Questions/problems i have

- i don't have a good template to give to the designer ( i found https://dribbble.com/shots/4108255-Responsive-PSD-and-Figma-Grid and download web.1920.psd). The current design layout is pixel perfect for a 1920x1080 screen. I am in the midst of telling them the layout is responsive and not equal in pixels for all screens
- i am also using https://github.com/BenWhitehead/bootstrap-big-grid and i like use the col-fhd-x classes, i don't see where the container width is being set for the 1920 break width (which should be 1890px (1920-30)?)
- based on the 1910.psd template i assumed 2 colums would be 250px in width?? but it is 281.xxxx

Any tips how to design for bigger screens with bootstrap??

Comment: why not just create your own media query with your own col-xxl classes for that

Comment: https://github.com/BenWhitehead/bootstrap-big-grid/blob/master/less/variables.less#L3

Comment: @pbenard I am not familar with .less and I am not seeing bootstrap/css/less/grid.less on my local setup, althought the browser seems to point to this file? If i find grid.less or variables.less should i just add the BenWhitehead variables for -fhd-xxx

or would this be all i need '@media (min-width: 1920px) {
        .container {
            width: 1890px;
        }
    }'

Comment: @pbenard i was able to recompile bootstrap.css with the new variables.less, but when i look into the new compiled bootstrap.css i can't see .container width for 1920px? All css definitions are @ media (min-width: 1920px) { but not for .container? I am doing something wrong??

Comment: Have you got an url to share where i can see your css ?

Comment: Tx for taking the time. But sorry i don't have a live url. Developing local (XAMPP).....but should there be a .container definition for the 1920px? and if not can i just add '@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  .container {
    width: 1890px;
  }
}' to the newly compiled bootstrap.css